# Issue with variables and proc oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, procedure

Im a beginner in oracle and i need help. I want to use variables in my proc but I dont know how to do it. I want to affect a string value to a variable depending to an other variable but when i lunch my proc nothing is happened. The code is not passing through the IF statement and I dont know why.

What I tried to do :

```
PROCEDURE contractual_control(p_id_depot IN depot.id_depot%TYPE) IS
-- Code_out proc
v_cod_out varchar(15) := null;  
-- List of CODE KO_FCT
ko_fct_01 varchar(15) := 'KO_FCT_01';
ko_fct_02 varchar(15) := 'KO_FCT_02';
ko_fct_03 varchar(15) := 'KO_FCT_03';
ko_fct_04 varchar(15) := 'KO_FCT_04';
-- List of CODE KO_TEC
ko_tec_01 varchar(15) := 'KO_TEC_01';
ko_tec_02 varchar(15) := 'KO_TEC_02';

 BEGIN  

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- CC1 - Objets interdits avec Presse Export - JIRA 968
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
SELECT ko_fct_04 INTO v_cod_out FROM DEPOT_IMPORT
WHERE DEPOT_IMPORT.ID_ZONE IS NOT NULL
AND DEPOT_IMPORT.TYP_ELEMENT IN ('ENCART','INCARTO','INCPLUS','OPP');

IF v_cod_out is not null THEN
  insert into babas_test values ('code retours = ' || v_cod_out);
ELSE
  insert into babas_test values ('Pas de code retours');
END IF;

COMMIT;
END contractual_control;
```

Comment: *"The code is not passing through the IF statement "* So what is actually happening? Do you get a runtime error? The value `'Pas de code retours'` inserted into that table? Please remember, we cannot run your code so we only know **what you tell us**.

Comment: I've no error in my package and there is no insertion in the table babas_test

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your select statement ,probably it returns more than one row.

```
SELECT ko_fct_04  FROM DEPOT_IMPORT
   WHERE DEPOT_IMPORT.ID_ZONE IS NOT NULL
   AND DEPOT_IMPORT.TYP_ELEMENT IN ('ENCART','INCARTO','INCPLUS','OPP');
```

also you can add `exception` to your procedure to see the errors.

```
exception when others then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ERROR :' || SQLERRM );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I found the probleme, I can not insert to the babas table because the proc doesnt know if the v_cod_out is null or empty or something else. I modify the proc to get the number of line back to my query. And then I insert to babas table depending of the number of line that i get.